# Django MonitorField() not working with Foreign Key if when condition is added

Tags: python, django, django-model-utils

Greeting, as mention in the question, my MonitorField stop updating the date when I add a `when` condition in it, below is my code :

```
class A(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class B(models.Model):
 status = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=4, null=True)
 monitor = fields.MonitorField(monitor='status', when=[1])
```

Comment: I don't think you can use `MonitorField`s with foreign key ids. You might try `monitor='status_id'` instead but I doubt that it would work.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but unfortunately it doesnt work

Answer (score -1):

You missed comma between monitor and when field

```
monitor = fields.MonitorField(monitor='status', when=[1])
```

Check this issue of django-model-utils on github if above doesnt work [LINK](https://github.com/jazzband/django-model-utils/issues/140)

Comment: Hi @Vaibhav, my apologies, I edited my code when i made this post, the comma is in my code, it still not working and yes I already saw the post in the github as well, he has very similiar issue with me but no solution either.

Comment: for me its working for same code, i created 2 model and when i am saving B (with [1]) its changing with new time i am giving

Comment: 1) I created A-model (say - a1),  2) I create B-model with a1,  3) I modified b1 with different date and time and its working

Comment: "3) I modified b1 with different date and time and its working" its should be auto update, when status is change to your case a1